# Predicting same values for entire test Set in MATLAB using LIBSVM

Tags: matlab, libsvm

I am using Support Vector Regression(SVR) in libsvm package to predict outputs. Kernel : RBF

Train set size : 729x40
Test set size : 137x40

The output of train set seems fine when measured against ground truth. But the predictions on test set are all the same. It outputs same values.

After checking the related posts, I normalized the data and played with the values of gamma(10-100000) but still the problem persists.

```
trainGT=games(((games(:,46)>=2010) & (games(:,46)<2015) & (games(:,1)~=8)),43);
featuresTrain=lastGame(games,true,1);
testGT=games((games(:,46)>=2015 & (games(:,1)~=8)),43);
featureTest=lastGame(games,false,1);  
eval(['model = svmtrain( trainGT, featuresTrain,''-s 4 -t 2 -c 10 -g 10 '  ''');']);
w = (model.sv_coef' * full(model.SVs));
b = -model.rho;

predictionsTrain = svmpredict(trainGT, featuresTrain,model); 
predictionsTest = svmpredict(zeros(length(testGT),1), featureTest, model);
```

My output is as follows

```
optimization finished, #iter = 1777
epsilon = 0.630588
obj = -19555.036253, rho = -17.470386
nSV = 681, nBSV = 118
Mean squared error = 305.214 (regression)
Squared correlation coefficient = -1.#IND (regression)
```

All my predictionTest values are 17.4704 (which is same as the rho value in the output). Can someone please help me on this? Thanks.